# how to add condition removing a class -

Tags: javascript

I created a simple gallery with images resized on click and added "x" to image containers which remove the class (.bigger). However, I'm trying to figure out how to add another class (.invisible) that will remove "x" when the selected image has no class (.bigger). Can you help out a beginner coder?

How to make a condition: if an image DOES NOT have class .bigger, add class .invisible (to the cross)? I'm really grateful for any help.

```js
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const crosses = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer span");

for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
  imgList[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgList.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("bigger"));

    imgList[i].classList.add("bigger");
  });
}

for (let x = 0; x < crosses.length; x++) {
  crosses[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgList.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("bigger"));
    crosses[x].classList.remove("invisible");
  });
}

if (imgList[i].classList.contains("")) {
  crosses[x].classList.add("invisible");
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.imgContainer span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bigger {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Tokyo1" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Tokyo2" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img3.jpg" alt="Tokyo3" />
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any change.

Comment: This doesn't need an extra class. Make the spans invisible to begin with, and then show them when the parent element _does_ have that specific class. `.imgContainer span { display: none; } .imgContainer.bigger span { display: block; }`

Comment: What you say makes sense but the crosses have disappeared and don't turn up again.  .imgContainer span {
  display: none;
} .imgContainer.bigger span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you iterate over the `.imgContainer`, you can more easily access the corresponding `img` and `span`.

Additionally, you can change the `invisible`css class to more specific `.imgContainer span.invisible` because `.imgContainer span {display: block}`  would overwrite it.

```js
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer img");
const crossList = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer span");

document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer").forEach((container) => {
  const img = container.querySelector("img");
  const cross = container.querySelector("span");

  img.addEventListener("click", function () {
    // Reset the classes of all images and spans.
    imgList.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("bigger"));
    crossList.forEach((el) => el.classList.add("invisible"));
    // make the image bigger and show the cross.
    img.classList.add("bigger");
    cross.classList.remove("invisible");
  });

  cross.addEventListener("click", function () {
    img.classList.remove("bigger");
    cross.classList.add("invisible");
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.imgContainer span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}
.imgContainer span.invisible {
  display: none;
}

.bigger {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span class="invisible">&times;</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Tokyo1" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span class="invisible">&times;</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Tokyo2" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span class="invisible">&times;</span>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Tokyo3" />
</div>
```

Comment: Jose, it almost does the trick. However, the crosses appear at the very beginning when there was no click event. After that when I start clicking they disappear and behave as I want them to. In addition, the crosses at the very beginning have a weird event - they disappear when I click on them.

Comment: Is a CSS problem, @TomDev. `.imgContainer span {display: block;}` has more importance (is more specific) that `.invisible { display: none;}`. You can change the last to `.imgContainer .invisible { display: none;}` or ad a `!important`. I will update with a full code example ASAP.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const imgList = document.querySelectorAll("img");
const crosses = document.querySelectorAll(".imgContainer span");

for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
  imgList[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgList.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("bigger"));
    this.classList.add("bigger");
    changeAction();
  });
}

for (let x = 0; x < crosses.length; x++) {
  crosses[x].addEventListener("click", function() {
    imgList.forEach((el) => el.classList.remove("bigger"));
    this.classList.remove("invisible");
  });
}

function changeAction() {
  for (let i = 0; i < imgList.length; i++) {
    if (imgList[i].classList.contains("")) {
      crosses[x].classList.add("invisible");
    }
  }
}
```

```css
img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 120px;
  object-fit: cover;
  margin: 0 1rem;
  opacity: 0.5;
  transition: all 0.2s;
}

img:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.imgContainer {
  position: relative;
}

.imgContainer span {
  position: absolute;
  top: -5px;
  right: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: block;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  background-color: transparent;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 15px;
  font-size: 30px;
}

.bigger {
  width: 500px;
  height: auto;
  opacity: 1;
}

.invisible {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img1.jpg" alt="Tokyo1" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img2.jpg" alt="Tokyo2" />
</div>
<div class="imgContainer">
  <span>&times;</span>
  <img src="img3.jpg" alt="Tokyo3" />
</div>
```